# Facebook Graph API - What's the name of the array me/likes returns?

Tags: javascript, json, facebook

I use de Javascript SDK to connect to the Facebook Graph API and retrieve my own likes. My code returns an array in JSON in the console with several objects. What is the name of the array it returns?

I need to know this so I can target specific fields of each object and display them on a webpage through JS & HTML.

My Graph API call:

```
function getLikes() {
        FB.api(
            "/me/likes",
            function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    console.log(response)
                }
            }
);
```

The JSON response in the console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Rb7.png

Comment: Please post the JSON you're referring to, and your Graph API call. Normally, you should easily be able to identify the `likes` property via `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

Easy one:

```
GET /me?fields=id,name,likes
```

outputs something like

```
{
  "id": "372934792749234729479", 
  "name": "Firstname Lastname", 
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Golf", 
        "category": "Sport", 
        "id": "105942022769573", 
        "created_time": "2015-01-01T14:45:39+0000"
      }
    ], 
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "Njg0MTM5ODQyMjk=", 
        "after": "MTA1OTQyMDIyNzY5NTcz"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so `likes.data` is the thing you want.

Here's an example on how to show the likes:

```
function getLikes() {
    FB.api("/me/likes", function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log(response);

            response.data.forEach(function(like, index, array) {
                console.log("Like " + (index+1) + ": " + like.name + " with id " + like.id);
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: My experience with JS is nihil. I'm not sure how to use the GET request. I will figure this out when I got some free time, but thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: Sorry man, but from your screenshot it's crystal clear how to "reach" the data from the JSON. Please read the FB Graph API docs and at least a little about JS. StackOverflow is not a programming service.

Comment: I apologize for taking a shortcut. I've been through tons of pages of the Graph API documentation and I couldn't find enough information about my problem. Perhaps it's indeed caused by the lack of JS experience.

Thank you again for your help though. Have a nice day Tobi.

Comment: No need to apologize, it's all good. What I mean is that your code is nearly complete. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Tobi, you're a superstar. Thank you, I've replaced the ID with the category and I got myself a nice list of all the subjects I liked. Have a great day!